# How to output Bash heredoc blocks using PHP heredoc

Tags: php, heredoc

I need to display a bash script on a webpage without any formatting.

The bash script uses standard 'here document' blocks. When I try to output the script using the PHP heredoc function, it cuts off the output when it encounters a '<<' sub-string. I thought the PHP heredoc function did not require escaping.

How do I output this script correctly?

```
<?php

$string = $_GET["string"];

$bashscript = <<<MYMARKER
<pre>

#!/bin/sh
rm /tmp/blue.sh
cat <<INSTALL > /tmp/blue.sh
#!/bin/sh
cd /tmp
mkdir output
cd output
cat <<EOF > interface.conf
remote $string
EOF
INSTALL

</pre>
MYMARKER;

echo $bashscript;

?>
```

The output I get on the page is

```
#!/bin/sh
rm /tmp/blue.sh
cat < /tmp/blue.sh
#!/bin/sh
cd /tmp
mkdir output
cd output
cat < interface.conf
remote 
EOF
INSTALL
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `<INSTALL >` and `<EOF >` are interpreted as tags in your browser (unrecognized though). Open it with right click -> view source and you'll see it right.
Just move out the `<pre>` and use [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) to display it correctly:

```
$bashscript = <<<MYMARKER
... everything without the <pre> tags ...
MYMARKER;

echo '<pre>'.htmlspecialchars($bashscript).'</pre>';
```

Comment: Thanks, I should have picked that up, time for a break!

Comment: Happens to us all; glad I could help